# Upgrade available for Open GL graphics card

Tags: imac

Is there a compatible Open GL graphics card for my 17-inch iMac
(MA590LL) to support 3D software?

Answer (score 1):

It's an integrated chip, so no, no upgrade is possible for this generation of iMacs.